# Merge hyphenated word in python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to merge a hyphenated word in pythog. For example I have:

```
bla bla bla infor-
mation bla bla bla
```

I want to end up with `blabla information bla bla bla`.

I can match up the hyphen, remove the newline, all that stuff is easy, but I can't seem to get the two parts to join. The closes I got was `bla bla bla infor mation bla bla`, but obviously I can not match on a space without removing all other spaces.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why would you ever use regex for such a simple task?

```
>>> s = """bla bla bla infor-
... mation bla bla bla"""
>>> s.replace('-\n','')
'bla bla bla information bla bla bla'
```

Answer (score 4):

You can replace `-` with preceding and following space with an empty string: -

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "bla bla bla infor- mation bla bla bla"
>>> re.sub("\s*-\s*", "", s)
'bla bla bla information bla bla bla'
```

If you have new line at the end of `hyphen`: -

```
>>> s = """bla bla bla infor-
mation bla bla bla"""
>>> re.sub("\s*-\s*\n", "", s)
'bla bla bla information bla bla bla'
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `str.split()` and `str.strip()`:

```
In [4]: strs="""bla bla bla infor-
   ...: mation bla bla bla"""

In [6]: "".join(x.strip() for x in strs.split("-\n"))
Out[6]: 'bla bla bla information bla bla bla'
```